# ads code can't work through js injection?

Tags: ads

I want to dynamically inject ads code such as google adsense into my webpage by JS. But several trials are all failed.
1.I try to do so:

```
<div class="advertisement">test</div>
<script>
  (function(){
   var s = document.getElementsByClassName('card-description')[0];
  if( s) {
     s.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>       agoda_ad_client = '17';       agoda_ad_width = 728;       agoda_ad_height = 90;</scr"+"ipt>";

    var adsrc = document.createElement('script');
    adsrc.type = "text/javascript";
    adsrc.src = "http://banner.agoda.com/js/show_ads.js";
    s.appendChild(adsrc);
   }


  })();
</script>
```

the ads code has been injected into div. But no ads displays.
2.it I put the ads code directly in div without any js. iT SHOWS THE ADS.

I have tried agoda's ads and google adsense. they are the same result.
Why??

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert javascript code with innerHTML. If you do that then it will be threated as inner content, not as javascript code. 
So, this line is wrong and won't work as you expected:

```
s.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>       agoda_ad_client = '17';       agoda_ad_width = 728;       agoda_ad_height = 90;</scr"+"ipt>";
```

Instead of that you can use document.write. As it is not a good idea do it in a syncronichous way, you can simple do this:

```
var adsenseTag = "...";
var if = document.createElement("iframe");
if.open();
if.contentDocument.write(adsenseTag);
if.close();
document.getElementsByClassName('card-description')[0].appendChild(if);
```

Remember to set in "adsenseTag" variable your Adsense tag as a string. Then it will write the content in an iframe, and as it uses a different instance of "document" it will be async.